# how to convert blob string format to image in xml parsing

Tags: iphone, xml-parsing

I need your help for converting string formated blob valu to image format.
I have a xml file,in that one field with BLOB type.I parsed that field into a string.Now I want display image from that string formated blob.
Please give me any idea for this solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expect your BLOB is `Base64` encoded. In that case you can use this Nick Lockwood's category to decode `Base64` string to `NSData` https://github.com/nicklockwood/Base64 and create `UIImage` from `NSData`.

Example code:

```
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithBase64EncodedString:blobString];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```

Comment: Thanks for answering.But it giving an error "No known class method for selector dataWithBase64EncodedString".What this error mean...?

Comment: Yes, you must add category from the link above to the project and import it's header file. Or most simple solution: if you don't know how to import category, just copy&paste method's code